# react-moment, is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, momentjs

Estoy haciendo un simple sistemas de comentarios con firebase para probar esta tecnologia.
todo perfecto hasta que implemento `react-moment`.
En la primera carga funciona, el tema es que cuando agrego un nuevo comentario creashea, y en la consola obtengo `date.toDate() is not a function`.
Adicionalmente estoy usando redux y lei que al momento de concatenar el nuevo valor (osea el ultimo comentario) la propiedad del date (que calculo es una funcion) se pierde.
Pero no se como solucionarlo.

La lógica que manejo es la siguiente:

1. Doy click en el post
2. Llego al post
3. Obtengo el id de la url
4. El id lo paso a una action

En la action hago la consulta hacia firebase

```
            const q = query(commentsRef, where("reviewId", "==", idReview) ,orderBy('date'));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            const comments = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                comments.push({id:doc.id,...doc.data()})
                
            });
```

Una vez tengo los datos hago el dispatch hacia el reducer

`dispatch(setCommentReview(comments))`

y asi tengo los comentarios en

```
 const {  comments } = useSelector(state => state.comment)
```

se muestran correctamente de la siguiente manera

```
<Box w='full'>
        <Flex justifyContent='space-between' >
          <Text>{name} dijo : </Text>
         <Moment fromNow>{date?.toDate()}</Moment>
        </Flex>
        <Text>{theComment}</Text>
      </Box>
```

pero al crear un nuevo comentario

```
export const CommentForm = ({idReview}) => {
    const { uid,photo,name } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    const [validateComment,setValidateComment] = useState(true)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [theComment, handleInputChange] = useForm({
        comment: '',
        uid,
        photo,
        name,
        reviewId:idReview,
        date: serverTimestamp(),
    })

    const { comment } = theComment

   

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(comment.length >= 6) {
            setValidateComment(false)
        }else{
            setValidateComment(true)
        }
    },[comment])

   

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(startCommentReview(theComment,idReview))
    }

    return (
        <Box as='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} bgColor='whiteAlpha.300' mt='4' p='4'>
            <Text>Deja un comentario</Text>
            <Textarea w='full' mt='4' type="text" name='comment' onChange={handleInputChange} value={comment}  />
            <Button type='submit' p='4' mt='4' bgColor='twitter.600' disabled={validateComment}>Comentar</Button>
        </Box>
    )
};
```

El dispatch sigue la misma logica, va al action

```
export const startCommentReview = (comment,idReview) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {

        const x = await addDoc(collection(db, 'reviews',idReview,'comments'), comment);
        dispatch(addComments(x.id,comment))
        

    }
}
```

```
const addComments = (id,comments) => {
    return {
        type: types.addComments,
        payload: {id,...comments}
    }
}
```

Pero no puede leer correctamente el valor de `date`

alguna ayuda?

EDIT:
pase date a  string y veo que los post que cargan la primera vez tienen este valor:

```
 {JSON.stringify(date)} //{"seconds":1642885966,"nanoseconds":281000000}
```

y cuando agrego un nuevo comentario

```
 {JSON.stringify(date)} //{"_methodName":"serverTimestamp"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despues de volverme loco me di cuenta que era problema de importaciones de las librerias.
estaba importando
import { db, collection, addDoc,getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite
y onSnapshot from 'firebase/firestore/'

todas tienen que venir de 'firebase/firestore/' sino no funciona.

y el moment tiraba error porque al guardar time en un redux y por algun motivo que aun desconozco si tenes un tipo date y lo pasas a redux  este despues no se lee como un objeto de tipo date.